# WatiN with webbrowser

Tags: .net, vb.net, browser, watin

I'm using the following code to bind watin to a webbrowser on the winform.

```
Dim w As IE = New IE(WebBrowser1.ActiveXInstance)
Settings.AutoStartDialogWatcher = False
w.GoTo("http://google.com")
```

I can see from wireshark that the page get's loaded, but the form is frozen until a exception gets thrown "Timeout while Internet Explorer busy".

Is there a way to bind watin to the webbrowser control ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, I think that this line:

```
Settings.AutoStartDialogWatcher = False
```

should be at the beginning, before `IE` instance is created.

Your code will work if you run it in separate thread.

Code in C# (sorry):

```
var thread = new Thread(() =>
{
    Settings.AutoStartDialogWatcher = false;
    var ie = new IE(webBrowser1.ActiveXInstance);
    ie.GoTo("http://www.google.com");
});
thread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
thread.Start();
```

Answer (score 0):

If I use this code it works

```
ie = New IE(WebBrowser1.ActiveXInstance)
ie.GoToNoWait("http://google.com")
While WebBrowser1.ReadyState <> WebBrowserReadyState.Complete
  Application.DoEvents()
End While
```

If it is not the best solution, but it works for me