# WatiN - working with WatIn in winForm

Tags: c#, winforms, watin

I start working with WatiN and I want to know, can I see the results without opening WatIn opening the browser automatically?

I mean, when I do:

```
using (var browser = new IE("http://www.google.com"))
{
    browser.TextField(Find.ByName("q")).Value = "GOGOOG";
}
```

it works great (and really fast), but I would like to see this inside a win Form without opening the browser.

So my real question is:

Can I use WatiN with the WebBrowser object/Control in winForm?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at this post:

[WatiN with webbrowser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3712599/watin-with-webbrowser)

There the ActiveX Instance is used to create an IE instance:

```
Settings.AutoStartDialogWatcher = false;
var ie = new IE(webBrowser1.ActiveXInstance);
ie.GoTo("http://www.google.com");
```

Comment: thank but i dont know why it throw an exception: System.ArgumentException: iwebBrowser2 needs to implement shdocvw.IWebBrowser2

Comment: nvm i miss the part that i need to use a new thred is working now, thank u very much :)